# Azure pipeline hosted agent support for .NET 5

Tags: .net, azure, azure-devops, azure-web-app-service

We have a .NET Core 3.1 project that we upgraded to .NET 5 as self-hosted agents in Azure Pipeline upgraded.

As per the .NET Core support policy -  https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/platform/support/policy/dotnet-core given EOL for .NET 5 is past what would be the effect on the self-hosted pipeline.

Is there any documentation for .NET version support on Azure hosted agent or does it follow the generic EOL timeline.

Comment: No doubt Azure follows the same lifecycle. Other cloud service providers won’t differ much.

Comment: My concerns was that the hosted agent upgraded around 6 months back why would Azure force another upgrade, if .NET 5 was already nearing EOL since you gained only a small windows an 6 would be a major change for projects on .NET Core 3.1

Comment: Check these Docs [Configure ASP.NET Core apps](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/app-service/configure-language-dotnetcore.md) [Microsoft-hosted agents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/hosted?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml)